# How to inspect DOM tree of React Native app?

Tags: debugging, dom, react-native

Is it possible to visually inspect the DOM tree of a React Native app, in the way you can inspect a regular Web page in Chrome's [Elements panel](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#dom-and-styles)? If so, how?

Comment: React Native does not have a DOM tree. It is creating native views, not creating a DOM.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The closest you're going to get is the inspector from the in-app developer menu (click show inspector).

[image]
[image]

To access the in-app developer menu:

**On iOS** shake the device or press control + ⌘ + z in the simulator.

**On Android** shake the device or press hardware menu button (available on older devices and in most of the emulators, e.g. in genymotion you can press ⌘ + m to simulate hardware menu button click)

Comment: Although i see the tabs for Inspect and Perf, 
I don't see the details view on iOS simulator for iphone 12 pro max for some reason

Answer (score 3):

For something closer to Chrome DevTool's Element panel, try using [react-native-debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger).

Works on: `windows`, `osx` and `linux`. It supports: `react native` and `redux`.

[image: react-native-debugger preview]